# How to enable grammar and spelling check in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

It seems by default Google Spreadsheets doesn't check spelling or grammar mistakes. It it possible to enable this feature? If possible then how?

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Doesn't it simply rely on your browser? What browser are you using?

Comment: @ale I am using chrome. Spelling and grammar checking works perfectly on google docs or any where in the web .

Comment: I think maybe you've found a bug. There's a "Spelling..." option under the _Tools_ menu, but it fails to find anything. It must of worked at some point, because also in the _Tools_ menu is a "Personal dictionary" option, and it has entries.

Answer (score 7):

Google Sheet is different for some reason to Google Docs.
In Google Sheet you need to select a range of cells or a column, a row and go to `Tools->Spelling` this will find spelling mistakes one by one.

Unlike Google Docs there is no check spelling as you type in Google Sheet.